# foreach statement cannot operate because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' with Tuples ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to build my view and join 2 tables using LINQ but i got this error in view in foreach in Model

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

This is my classes :

```
public partial class Lab_orders_Cash
    {
        [Display(Name = "Order Id")]
        public int cash_order_id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> order_date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "MRN File No.")]
        public Nullable<int> patient_no { get; set; }
        public string invoice_order_no { get; set; }
        public string order_description { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order Status")]
        public Nullable<int> order_status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> catid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> almansoor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> prio_id { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class Lab_Sample_status
    {
        public int status_id { get; set; }
        public string status_name { get; set; }
    }
```

this my controller :

```
public ActionResult ordersCash()
        {
         var OrdersList = from o in db.Lab_orders_Cash
           Join os in db.Lab_Sample_status on o.order_status equals os.status_id into tablestatus
                          where o.patient_no == (int)Session["UserpatientNo"]
                          select o;
            return View(OrdersList);



        }
```

In view i used Tuples :

```
@using AljawdahNewSite.Models;
@model Tuple<Lab_orders_Cash,Lab_Sample_status>
@{

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ordersCash";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
}

<h2>Orders List </h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.cash_order_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.order_date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.patient_no)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item2.status_name)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>




@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.cash_order_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.order_date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item1.patient_no)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Tuple => Tuple.Item2.status_name)
        </td>

        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.cash_order_id }) 

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

in foreach when select model i got this error , also i tried to use IEnumerable in view like this

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Lab_orders_Cash>,IEnumerable<Lab_Sample_status>>
```

but same error when i select Model it shows the error 
What i need to change to solve this error.

Comment: Your error is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: You model are expecting af Tuple<T1, T2> but you are giving it an IEnumerable. Either you should create a Tuple in the Controller or change your model to an IEnumerable.

Comment: In `from o in ... join os ... select o` the join is not effective. Your Action returns `IEnumerable<Lab_orders_Cash>` no order_status  included.

Comment: @Michael i updated for each loop and add Tuples items , what to do next how to add Tuple to controller or change model to an IEnumerable , i'm new to MVC :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman how to make it effective

Comment: I'm not sure how Lab_orders_Cash and Lab_Sample_status are related, but in short terms, the type of your `@model` needs to be the same type that you give to `View(...)` in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use another way like the following steps :

1- Create new class and put your tables in that class

```
public class Tables
    {

        public Lab_orders_Cash LabOrdersCash { get; set; }
        public Lab_Sample_status LabOrderStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

2- Write the controller like the following :

```
public ActionResult ordersCash()
        {
            List<Lab_orders_Cash> ordercash = db.Lab_orders_Cash.ToList();
            List<Lab_Sample_status> samplestatus = db.Lab_Sample_status.ToList();

            var OrdersList = from o in ordercash
                 join st in samplestatus on o.order_status equals st.status_id
                 where o.patient_no == (int)Session["UserpatientNo"]
              select new Tables{ LabOrdersCash = o , LabOrderStatus = st };

            return View(OrdersList);

        }
```

3- Create your view use the following code :

```
@model IEnumerable<AljawdahNewSite.Models.Tables>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ordersCash";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
}

<h2>Orders List</h2>

<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td> Order No. </td>
            <td> order date    </td>
            <td> Patient No  </td>
            <td> Status   </td>


        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.LabOrdersCash.cash_order_id</td>
                <td>@item.LabOrdersCash.order_date</td>
                <td>@item.LabOrdersCash.patient_no</td>
                <td>@item.LabOrderStatus.status_name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

This way more effective and easily you can add all your tables in this tables class and call this class any where in your project and easier than Tuples.